# Importing Cubical Agda modules in Agda

Tags: agda

I am using agda in Emacs mode. I am trying to start a project which relies on the cubical library. I want to import the module Cubical.Core.Everything. I have only written the following

```
{-# OPTIONS --without-K #-}

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
```

When I try to load the file I receive the following error

```
/home/rymndbkr/myHoTT/Agda/intro.agda:3,1-36
Importing module Cubical.Core.Everything using the
--cubical/--erased-cubical flag from a module which does not.
when scope checking the declaration
  open import Cubical.Core.Everything
/home/rymndbkr/myHoTT/Agda/intro.agda:3,1-36
Importing module Cubical.Core.Everything using the --two-level flag
from a module which does not.
when scope checking the declaration
  open import Cubical.Core.Everything
```

I've read through the relevant agda documentation and I don't see anything that addresses this. Does anyone have an idea of whats happening here?

Comment: I think the error message is clear enough here: The imported module has `--cubical`, but yours does not; So you need to add that flag. What would you suggest as an improved error message, if you find it confusing?

Comment: @Trebor I did not know that flags and options are the same thing. I guess I should know that. Honestly, I am not a programmer and am very bad at these things. I'm just trying to learn how to start working in univalent mathematics and HoTT. So, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cubical Agda libraries can only be used from Cubical Agda. The error message is telling you to change your source file to use Cubical mode:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for dumb question...